# Kafka streams topic merge message consumption order

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm building a kafka streams application where several topics are merged into one.

The application seems to want to read all messages from the first topic, and only then proceed reading from the next one. I would like my application to switch reading from another topic after consuming 100 records.

Is it possible with kafka streams?

Edit: streams are merged using KStream::merge and are statefully transformed:

```
kstream1.merge(kstream2)
    .merge(kstream3)
    ...
    .merge(kstreamN)
    .transform(transformer, stateStore)
    .to(output)
```

The application is single-threaded and all topics have one partition.

Comment: Hi, How many topics/partitions per topic and also stream threads are you using.  Is it a single stream processor reading from all topics? With proper configuration they should be processed in parallel one exception would be is you use a GlobalKTable in a join so in that case that topic to populate the GKTable would be fully processed before joining.

Comment: It's not possible to limit the number and switch without first grouping/aggregating the data before the join.

Comment: @groo I added the information you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what program you wrote, but the simplest way would be `stream1.merge(stream2)`. For this case, data should be processed interleaved between both base on timestamp order.

Using a custom timestamp extractor, you could maybe interleave between both in 100 records increments.

Comment: `stream1.merge(stream2)` is is exactly what I'm doing. After I reset the application with the shell utility with `--from-beginning`, the first topic is read, and then, the second one.

Comment: Did you check the record timestamps? If the timestamp of the records in one topic are smaller, it's expected that those are processed first.

Comment: Timestamps of messages in those topics are interleaved. The application does not even poll the other topic once.

Comment: That is weird -- what version of Kafka Streams are you using? Can you try increasing `max.task.idle.ms` config?

Comment: My mistake, we were adding timestamps in message body and not in headers. This fixed the issue. Than you.